# Chrome extension pop up on specific pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a google chrome extension and I want to make this pop up on specific web pages. I dont want the function alert to give notifications, I want the whole extension to open automatically when I visit certain sites.Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The standard browserAction/pageAction popup cannot open automatically so you'll have to add the popup as a DOM element inside the page (using a content script), or show a Notification API bubble, or display a separate small window using chrome.windows.create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a content script, you can run some code triggered by the onload event, which could do something like:

```
someExistingElement.append(myPopUp);
```

or

```
parentElement.insertBefore(myPopUp, parentElement.firstChild);
```

Your popup likely contains many internal nodes, so if you want to avoid adding these to the DOM one at a time with a series of createElement statements (which you almost certainly do), you can constuct the popup in a template and then add the whole template to the DOM in one step.

(See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: So if i'm getting this right, I have to create a content sript like popup.js which in certain urls trigger the extension to pop. The function of the onload event that triggers the extension is chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener? And where exactly in my code I will mark the urls I want?

Comment: I haven't looked at chrome extensions in a while, but I popped over to the docs (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and now I see/recall that there's a content_scripts property in the extension's manifest file. 

It could look like `"content_scripts": [{ "matches": ["*://*.some-website.com/*"],"js": ["my-script.js"]}` (but much prettier from not all being smushed onto one line.)


You can choose to match several different pages (or even sites) for you script to run on, but it sounds like you just want a single one.